# Где httpd.conf в VestaCP

Tags: linux, администрирование, php.ini, httpd, vesta

Нужно изменить настройки php в разделе Directory но только для одного домена.
Где их поменять? Файлов несколько:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно, по крайней мере на CentOS конфиги для сайтов генерируются в папке пользователя на каждый домен. Например для пользователя admin, конфиги его сайтов лежат так

```
/home/admin/conf/web/httpd.conf
```